# How to fit long text in a button?

Tags: java, android

My button is fixed size height. I need it to be like the text on the left on my picture below. Now it's like on the right. I've tried every gravity option but no result. Is there a way to accomplish this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/joPqD.jpg

Comment: Could you put the `layout_height="wrap_content"`?

Comment: One Posibility Reduse the Text Size if you can. `android:textSize="6sp"` else there is no way to put long text in a fixed size button.

Comment: My text is very small as it is. I'm afraid it'll be to small.

Comment: [here](http://i.imgur.com/wAcWdMT.jpg) you can see my actual button. Ass you can see it's very small font. But, from the bottom green line to my text there is some space and it covers my text. Is there a way to use that space? I don't get it, why does it cover my text? Isn't that....just plain stupid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If wrap_content as height doesn't match your needs you probarbly have to change the textsize. Also singleLine = false might help...

Also android Button comes with a default padding so you should set i to 0.

Comment: No, singleLine did not help. Also I can't wrap_content, cause I need fixed button height.

Comment: Then a reduction of the font size is probarbly your only option.

Comment: Actually that did not work either. My font is now barely visible, and still can't fit two lines of text. Other line is cut in half, at best. And above first line there is space for at least two lines of text. It's like it starts from the middle of my button and goes down with second line, but the first line never moves a bit up.

Comment: BRAVO MY MAN!! Can you edit your main answer so I can accept it? Thank you very much.